# Warning in install.packages lib is not writeable in R studio

Tags: r, directory, path, rstudio

Extremely frustrated that I am not able to install the following package:

`install.packages('tseries')`

after I run this command I get the following message:

> Would you like to use a personal library instead?

I click `"yes"`

Then it attempts to download a bunch of things from R URLs.

Then I get the following error where it mentions

> Warning in install packages: lib = "My path" is not writable

I have read multiple things that mentioned that I need to set myself as administrator with full control/access.

I have done so and allowed full control to my personal account.

I then restart R and try to install the `tseries` package again but I get the same exact errors as mentioned above.

System windows 10

R version 3.6

Comment: Can you show exactly what's show in the R console when you run these steps. You shouldn't need administrator permissions to install packages in R under normal circumstances.

Comment: Sorry I uninstalled and then about to install again. As I mentioned all it is  "Warning in install packages: lib = "My path"

Comment: I would want to see the entire output, including the command you entered. Just copy/paste everything you see in the console when running that command.

Comment: install.packages("tseries")
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library"' is not writable
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot create dir 'C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.6', reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : unable to create ‘C:/Users/santi/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’